# not able to starting OracleXNTNSListener in windows environment

Tags: windows, oracle

I have installed oracleXE in my local meachine.

I have changed the services of Oracle level Automatic to Manual.
Know when i start the Oracle Services all are getting started except the OracleXNTNSListener service.

It saying some times  below mentioned 1 error or 2 error

1>Windows could not start OracleXETNSListner service on Local Computer.

Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly.

OR

2>The OracleXNTNSListener service on Local Computer startred and then stopped.Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After some trials the listener got started.

What I did is for this, I have edited the listener.ora file.

In this line intialy HOST = hostname was there, I changed that to localhost ip i.e 127.0.0.1

(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(**HOST = 127.0.0.1**)(PORT = 1521))

Comment: I had my laptop readded to the domain which changed the system name.
had to find the listener.ora and update the host to the system name from the system information on windows machine. C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN

Answer (score 6):

I know its a very old thread but, changing `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` in both `listener.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` helped me.

Answer (score 4):

My `listener.ora` file was like this

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my_computer_name)(PORT = 1521))
```

I changed to

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem, because I have installed Oracle 12c previous, then I try to install Oracle 11g express.

Check this registry key to ensure ORACLE_HOME is configured for the service:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_XE\ORACLE_HOME
```

If that doesn't exist, check here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_XE\ORACLE_HOME
```

Also make sure this other key isn't pointing to your old client registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_XE\ORACLE_HOME_KEY
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_XE\ORACLE_HOME_KEY
```

- Check if the system variable ORACLE_HOME is set to `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server` (or similar).

Answer (score 1):

Set the **environment variable** `ORACLE_HOME` to **your** oracle database home directory such as `C:\app\ora11g\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN`

Answer (score 0):

this might be caused because you changed your PC-NAME. Make sure in "listener.ora" file HOST = PC-NAME (eg: admin-PC).